# What is the use of canonical user id in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to my research, the canonical id of an IAM user is used to assign permissions for an S3 bucket.

Is that the only use case?

How can we use the canonical id in AWS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the name, the Canonical User ID does not represent an IAM user.  It represents an entire AWS account, and is only used by S3.  It's a holdover from the early days of AWS, before IAM.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html